# Replacing a pandas substring with value from a column/Series

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace a Pandas substring with the value from a pandas column. This question has not been answered before.

### I have tried using the .replace() method but it throws out the below error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 df['name'].str.replace('(C)', df.name2)
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py in
>   wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)    1841                 )    1842
>   raise TypeError(msg)
>   -> 1843             return func(self, *args, **kwargs)    1844     1845         wrapper.**name** = func_name
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py in
>   replace(self, pat, repl, n, case, flags, regex)    2714     def
>   replace(self, pat, repl, n=-1, case=None, flags=0, regex=True):
>   2715         result = str_replace(
>   -> 2716             self._parent, pat, repl, n=n, case=case, flags=flags, regex=regex    2717         )    2718         return
>   self._wrap_result(result)
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py in
>   str_replace(arr, pat, repl, n, case, flags, regex)
>       597     # Check whether repl is valid (GH 13438, GH 15055)
>       598     if not (is_string_like(repl) or callable(repl)):
>   --> 599         raise TypeError("repl must be a string or callable")
>       600 
>       601     is_compiled_re = is_re(pat)
>
> TypeError: repl must be a string or callable

```
data = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'name': ['name1 (C)', 'name2 (B)', 'name3', 'name4'],
        'name2':['Jane','Abbie','Luke','Peter']}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['name'].str.replace('\(C\)', df.name2)
```

Expected Result:

```
    id  name    name2
0   1   name1 Jane  Jane
1   2   name2 Abbie Abbie
2   3   name3   Luke
3   4   name4   Peter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need python `re.sub` and listcomp

```
import re

df['new_name'] = [re.sub(r'\(\w+\)', r, s) for r, s in zip(df.name2, df.name)]

Out[280]:
   id       name  name2     new_name
0   1  name1 (C)   Jane   name1 Jane
1   2  name2 (B)  Abbie  name2 Abbie
2   3      name3   Luke        name3
3   4      name4  Peter        name4
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other solution that doesn't use regex?

Comment: Yes. You may use `str.split` and conditional replace and join back. It requires you know exact location of sub-strings you want to replace(as in your sample they are 2nd word) and it is not optimal to split and join back.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Makes sense. I'll go with the regular expressions