# Replacing a substring with a value from a column - part 2

Tags: python, pandas

This is similar to a post I made yesterday.([Replacing a pandas substring with value from a column/Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58806272/replacing-a-pandas-substring-with-value-from-a-column-series/58807149?noredirect=1#comment103896187_58807149)), but this is slightly more difficult. For the field , name, I want to replace the substrings inside the brackets with the name of the field they represent

For example in row 1: name holds the value 'name1 (name3)
I want to replace the substring '(name3)' with the value in the field called name3.
So name now becomes 'name1 Simon'

```
data = {'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'name': ['name1 (name3)', 'name2 (name2)', 'name3', 'name4 (name2) (name3)'],
    'name2':['Jane','Abbie','Luke','Peter'],
   'name3': ['Simon','Peter','Annie','Robinson']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

import re

df['new_name'] = [re.sub(r'\(\w+\)', r, s) for r, s in zip(df.name2, df.name)]
```

Expected Results :

```
ID  name    name2   name3
0   1   name1 Simon Jane    Simon
1   2   name2 Abbie Abbie   Peter
2   3   name3   Luke    Annie
3   4   name4 Peter Robinson    Peter   Robinson
```

Actual Results:

```
ID  name    name2   name3
0   1   name1 Jane  Jane    Simon
1   2   name2 Abbie Abbie   Peter
2   3   name3   Luke    Annie
3   4   name4 Peter Peter   Peter   Robinson
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using `apply`

**Ex:**

```
data = {'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'name': ['name1 (name3)', 'name2 (name2)', 'name3', 'name4 (name2) (name3)'],
    'name2':['Jane','Abbie','Luke','Peter'],
   'name3': ['Simon','Peter','Annie','Robinson']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
import re

def foo(val):
    return re.sub(r"\((.*?)\)", lambda y: val[y.group(1)], val['name'])

df['new_name'] = df.apply(foo, axis=1)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   ID                   name  name2     name3              new_name
0   1          name1 (name3)   Jane     Simon           name1 Simon
1   2          name2 (name2)  Abbie     Peter           name2 Abbie
2   3                  name3   Luke     Annie                 name3
3   4  name4 (name2) (name3)  Peter  Robinson  name4 Peter Robinson
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, please can you explain how the function works? Just so I can adapt it to what im facing at work?